# WebClient - DownloadFileCompleted wenn accessing 404 URL

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I use
private void Completed

```
public void DonwloadFile()
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("resource to download"), reportFileName );
}
   private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            //do some stuff
        }
```

This works, but if the "resource to download" is not available (returns 404) an empty file is created at "reportFileName". I can ofcourse check `AsyncCompletedEventArgs`  in Completed and see the exception, but then the empty file is already created.

Is there a way to handle 404 in a way that not empty file is created?

Comment: Why does it matter if you create an empty file? Just delete it afterwards if it couldn't do the download.

Comment: I will actually do that if there is no other way, but it doesnt feel good.

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner - Then check the size of the file and if its 0 bytes delete it.  You can also determine if you were sent to an error page easy enough.